# Sharepoint Server not delivering Mails to AD users

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I have SP2016 on premise, configured wtih gmail SMTP. Tested emails on SMTP, it delivers fine.

Issues: Sharepoint doesnt send emails, tried using powershell commands - returned false (event 7946) - ULS (Failed attempt 2 sending mail to recipients: peter.okachie@gmail.com. Mail Subject: Test mail subject. Error: SmtpException while sending email: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Server does not support secure connections.)

Tried everything on the internet, same error. My users in my AD are using an external email hosted abroad.

Tried Hmailserver, using local mail. Same error. Being seeing this error: darkcode for emailnotification disabled

Please help with me a solution.

Comment: Have you tried enabling TLS encryption in your outgoing mail settings?

Comment: Yes, done that, both on IIS Level and SP2016 CAdmin. Still getting same error. SP2016 is on VM, I have tested the SMTP server by putting email in pickup and I received the mail test. I have explored all known solutions

Comment: The outgoing SMTP settings should point to the gmail servers.  There's no need to bounce the emails through IIS.

Comment: Tried that didnt still work. Can you do Teamviewer, just take a look at my environment. Thanks

Comment: The message is pretty clear. You have TLS enabled for outgoing email in SharePoint and the mail server does not support TLS. In addition, if your email server only accepts authenticated connections, you must send it through an anonymous relay.

Comment: Please look at my config:  https://snag.gy/Z3dRYj.jpg

Comment: @TrevorSeward I have my TLS set to no n Central Administration. Can you do teamviewer pls. I have exhausted all options

Comment: This isn't the best forum to ask for remote support. I'd suggest contacting a SharePoint consultant or opening a support case with Microsoft if you feel you cannot get support via StackExchange or other free means.